# Centering an image using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to center an image using boostrap's `fluid-container`, `img-responsive` and `center-block` (and `margin: 0 auto;` CSS) but I haven't been succesful so far.

The code I'm trying to implement is as follows:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
 <div class='row'>
  <img src="https://www.cartacapital.com.br/mais-admiradas/o-colecionador-de-
  empresas-5838.html/paulo-lemann/@@images/4dd0c0a1-9ae4-4fd2-8724-
  e59867bb14c1.jpeg" alt="Jorge Paulo Lemann" class="img-responsive center-block">
 </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't center the image. Any help?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using codepen: https://codepen.io/diegomengue/pen/WOwJYP. Is there a possibility codepen is  messing something up?

Comment: Works fine for me once the screen is wider than the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loaded bootstrap 4 in the pen, and `.center-block` is a bootstrap 3 feature. Add bootstrap 3 to the pen instead. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/qjaBNK

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
 <div class='container-fluid'>
  
  <div class='row'>
  
  <img src="https://www.cartacapital.com.br/mais-admiradas/o-colecionador-de-empresas-5838.html/paulo-lemann/@@images/4dd0c0a1-9ae4-4fd2-8724-e59867bb14c1.jpeg" alt="Jorge Paulo Lemann" class="img-responsive center-block" >
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `row` has `display: flex` here, you can add

```
.row {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

to center the image

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXgxgo